# Dropdown option list validate with bvalidator

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm using bValidator plugin on my local website, and I'm stuck with the last part of the form validation.

I'm trying to validate a dropdown list option, but somehow it doesn't work. There is probably a workaround to get this to work. I would really appreciate your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/2CLZj/

---

```
<br /><br /><br />

<input type="text" data-bvalidator="required" data-bvalidator-msg="message" name="some" id="some" />

<br />

<br />


<select id="branche_select" data-bvalidator="required">
 <option value="selecteer">Select your branche</option>
 <option value="Marketing">Branche A</option>
 <option value="Marketing">Branche B</option>

</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
```

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default option's `value` to `""`:

```
<select id="branche_select" data-bvalidator="required">
    <option value="">Select your branche</option>
    <option value="Marketing">Branche A</option>
    <option value="Marketing">Branche B</option>
</select>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rEF6h/